# 2005 chevy uplander-water in antifreeze reservoir?

Tags: engine

2005 Chevy Uplander V6 I have oil [coffee color] in reservoir and radiator fluid down some what. Never over heated. Seems to run a little cooler then normal  Oil in engine block and transmission looks fine.  engine has 162000 miles. Am I had?

Comment: I don't know if you're had, but your engine almost assuredly has a failed head gasket.

Answer (score 1):

The most likely problem in my opinion is a head gasket problem.  A reasonably proficient DIYer should be able to make that fix.  Of course a V6 has two heads and you really won't know which one is bad until you are well into it so it makes sense to replace both.

Other possibilities are a warped head, usually due to overheating, a cracked block, usually due to bad anti-freeze in cold weather.

I believe you'll find the oil pressure is forcing oil into the coolant and engine vacuum is pulling coolant into the cylinder and it ends up going out the tailpipe.